# dropwizard validation not failing on unknown properties

Tags: validation, jackson, dropwizard

I have the following class that I take as input in my Resource

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)
    public class InputRequest {
@NotEmpty
private List<String> names;

private DateTime startDate;

private DateTime endDate;

@ValidationMethod(message="startDate should be less than endDate")
public boolean isValidDates() {
    return startDate.isBefore(endDate);
}

@ValidationMethod(message = "one of the names is not valid")
public boolean isValidNames() {
    //do something
}

public List<String> getNames() {
    return names;
}

public void setNames(List<String> names) {
    this.names = names;
}

public DateTime getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(DateTime startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public DateTime getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(DateTime endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

}
```

The resource class is as follows

```
    public Response getData(@Auth String userId, @Valid InputRequest request) {
```

However, the following input is not causing any exceptions

```
{"names":["somename"],"startDate":1427155200000,"endDate":1427846400000, "x":"a"}
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

EDIT: Also if I send the following instead, its passing through

```
{"names":["somename"],"startDate":1427155200000}
```

I want it to fail if something field is missing

Comment: jackson (not hibernate-validator) fails on unknown properties by default. Maybe adding @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false) has broken it.

Comment: @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = false)  was added on second try. Initially it was not there and even then the validation did not fail.

Comment: If it's an existing code base that is new to you, maybe the objectmapper was configured that way and it may not be possible to undo that using the annotation; and that would probably a Jackson bug. See if there is `bootstrap.getObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);` somewhere in your Application class. You can also write a simple unit test with a brand new `new ObjectMapper()` to see how it works normally.

Answer (score 0):

```
    bootstrap.getObjectMapperFactory().enable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
```

worked for me